# calculate limit of $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}{x^6+y^6}$

Tags: limits

I need to calculate this limit:
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \cfrac{1}{x^6 + y^6} exp \Biggr(\cfrac{-1}{x^2 + y^2} \Biggl) $$

It should be zero. I thought about the sandwich theorem but I'm not sure what to do from here:

$$0\leq \Biggr|\cfrac{1}{x^6 + y^6} exp \Biggr(\cfrac{-1}{x^2 + y^2} \Biggl) \Biggr|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our goal is to show
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\;\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^6+y^6}\right)\!=0$$
Changing to polar coordinates, let
\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\theta)\\[4pt]
y=r\cos(\theta)\\
\end{cases}
Noting that for $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, the function
$$\theta \mapsto \cos^6(\theta)+\sin^6(\theta)$$
has positive minimum value, $a$ say, we get
$$
0 <
\frac
{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}
{x^6+y^6}
=
\frac
{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}
{r^6\bigl(\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^6(\theta)\bigr)}
\le
\frac
{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}
{ar^6}
$$
for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2{\setminus}\{(0,0)\}$.

Hence, to prove the desired limit, it suffices to prove
$$
\lim_{r\to {0^{+}}}
\frac
{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}
{r^6}
=
0
$$
Then, letting $u=\frac{1}{r^2}$, we get
$$
\lim_{r\to {0^{+}}}
\frac
{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}
{r^6}
=
\lim_{u\to \infty}
\frac{u^6}{e^u}
=
0
$$
as was to be shown.